# Regen default.prop

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow

So there is this settop box in india, called airtel internet tv(codename ganesa) It's gone 2 years with no updates, stuck on android 6. it has no usb adb but does have wireless adb. got root using dirtycow and updated default.prop to this:

## before

```
#
# ADDITIONAL_DEFAULT_PROPERTIES
#
ro.hardware=ganesa
ro.product.board=ganesa
ro.adb.secure=1
ro.secure=0
security.perf_harden=1
ro.allow.mock.location=0
ro.debuggable=0
ro.zygote=zygote32
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms=64m
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx=64m
dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms=64m
dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx=512m
ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge=0
debug.atrace.tags.enableflags=0
#
# BOOTIMAGE_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
ro.bootimage.build.date=Tue Jul 16 04:42:11 UTC 2019
ro.bootimage.build.date.utc=1563252131
ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint=airtel/ganesa/ganesa:6.0.1/MUE91/06.02.73:user/release-keys
persist.sys.usb.config=none
```

## after

```
#
# ADDITIONAL_DEFAULT_PROPERTIES
#
ro.hardware=ganesa
ro.product.board=ganesa
ro.adb.secure=0
ro.secure=1
security.perf_harden=1
ro.allow.mock.location=0
ro.debuggable=1
ro.zygote=zygote32
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms=64m
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx=64m
dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms=64m
dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx=512m
ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge=0
debug.atrace.tags.enableflags=0
#
# BOOTIMAGE_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
ro.bootimage.build.date=Tue Jul 16 04:42:11 UTC 2019
ro.bootimage.build.date.utc=1563252131
ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint=airtel/ganesa/ganesa:6.0.1/MUE91/06.02.73:user/release-keys
persist.sys.usb.config=none
```

After a quick reboot wifi adb went rip, I dont have a male-to-male usb cable rn, but can quickly make one if it is the only option!

So I would want to regen stock default.prop

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a male to male cable at the end and connected it, connected and restored default.prop .

:)